# Get command from input

Tags: python, string, list, input

```
commands = ['chat', 'call', 'exit', 'friends', 'status']

class MainHub(object):
    def menu(self):
        while True:
            selection = raw_input("> ")
            if selection != any(commands):
                print "Not a recognized command!\n"
            else:
                print selection
```

it prints "Not a recognized command!" everytime, even if selection is something like 'chat' or 'call'. It's a very simple snippet of code, but I just can't seem to see what's wrong with it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want the `any` function, you want the `not in` syntax:

```
if selection not in commands:
```

`any` is from predicate calculus and checks whether any of its inputs are `True`. In this case, you're comparing your input to `any(commands)`, which is `True` since there is a `True` element in `commands`.

Comment: For more information, check out the [Python reference](http://docs.python.org/library/). You can also find [`any`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any). For easier ways to find stuff in the reference, just do a search on it, or do a Google search (easier to do a Google search). For example, a search for 'Python any'.

Comment: I did refer to documentation for any(), but completely misread it. Oh well, I learned something today I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

> selection != any(commands)

This seems to be a very common class of errors for beginners, although I've only started noticing it recently. Another common attempt is to use things like `value == (3 or 4 or 5)`, which is fundamentally the same mistake.

In programming, comparison is comparison and set-membership testing is set-membership testing. They cannot be confused, they way they can in English. Programming requires us to be precise about what we mean, and not allow ourselves to be misled by casual phrasing of what we really mean.

What you have written means "if `selection` is not equal to (the truth-value of whether any of the `commands` is true)". The function call returns either `True` or `False` (in fact, it returns `True`, because at least one of the `commands` is a non-empty string - in fact, they all are - and non-empty strings are "true-ish" while empty strings are "false-ish"), and you compare `selection` to that value. It will never be equal, because `selection` is a string, and strings aren't even the same kind of thing as `True` or `False`, which are booleans, let alone equal.

What you meant was "if `selection` is not one of the `commands`", i.e. "if it is not the case that `selection` is contained within `commands`". That is a set-membership question, not a comparison one.

In Python, we accomplish set-membership testing using the `in` keyword. The grammar allows us to write the perfectly natural sounding `if selection not in commands:`, so we don't need to compromise with `if not (selection in commands):`.

Answer (score 1):

`any()` returns `True` if at least one of the elements in the argument iterable evaluates to `True`, and `False` otherwise. So, your code here:

```
if selection != any(commands):
```

Seeing as `commands` is a list of non-empty (thus, "true") strings, any will just return `True`. The code is left as:

```
if selection != True:
```

Which makes no sense :D. What you want to know is if `selection` exists in the list of commands, which you can do this way:

```
if selection not in commands:
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
if selection != any(commands):
```

For this other line:

```
if selection not in commands:
```